# What is the most appropriate way to handle queries when splitting data in Learning to Rank?

Tags: python, machine-learning, ranking, information-retrieval, train-test-split

We are exploring various ways to create the training and test sets to evaluate a Learning to Rank (LTR) model.

In a Learning to Rank scenario, for each query, there are a number of associated documents grouped according to their relevance judgments.

Therefore data splitting should be managed differently than other supervised machine learning techniques (where samples are simply split between training and test sets in a certain percentage) since two important elements need to be taken into account: the query Id and the relevance label.

How do I choose how to divide the data? What is the best approach to handle queries when creating the two sets? Are you splitting within a query or leave entire queries for the test? What is the approach that worked best for you?

Comment: leave entire queries for the test

Comment: Thanks, @LuckyQueen for your reply. Why do you think the query integrity approach is more correct than splitting within a query? Could you please elaborate and share your observations?